# Ajax get response body data name with space

Tags: ajax

I am able to read specific data from responses with ajax GET example by using data.investing.
but one of my data name is unrest and war and i am unsure how do i write it inside my javascript, as i tried data.unrest and war and it didnt work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "https://agile-bayou-24340.herokuapp.com/users/getTodayData",
          contentType: 'application/json',
          dataType: 'json',
          responseType: 'application/json',
          xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: false
          },
          headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/json',
          },
          success: function (data) {
              console.log(data.investing[0].title);
              $('#div1').html((data.investing[0].title));
          },
          error: function (error) {
              console.log("Error");
          }
      });
  });
});
```

this is my current code

Comment: can you share you `json` response?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse Json to Array and use key's

```
 success: function (data) {
          data = $.parseJSON(data)
          console.log(data['investing'][0]['title']);
          $('#div1').html((data['investing'][0]['title']));
      },
```